# Hide div inside (e.g. Twitter) shadow-dom with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, shadow-dom

Using TamperMonkey to streamline page view on my side, and wish to hide part of the externally-sourced Twitter card(s) from printing. The image in the EmbeddedTweet does not print anyway, and leaves a large empty rectangle that wastes valuable space.

The DOM looks like the image below - how would I target the DIV with class `SummaryCard-image` (green arrow)? It doesn't matter to me if the DIV is removed from the DOM, or just hidden with CSS.

I have tried the below methods, which do not work:

(1) Injecting CSS with `.SummaryCard-image{display:none !important;}`

(2) jQuery: `$('.SummaryCard-image').remove();`

`$('.SummaryCard-image').length` returns `0`

> (Note the `#shadow-root (open)`, 2nd element from the top)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the shadow root first inorder to traverse to that element. You need something like this

```
var twitterWidget= document.querySelector('twitterwidget').shadowRoot;
twitterWidget.querySelector('.SummaryCard-image').style.display = "none";
```

For multiple twitter widgets

```
    var twitterWidgets = document.querySelectorAll('twitterwidget'); 

    twitterWidgets.forEach(function(item){
      var root = item.shadowRoot; root.querySelector('.SummaryCard-image').style.display = 'none';
    })
```

Example
https://rawgit.com/ebidel/2d2bb0cdec3f2a16cf519dbaa791ce1b/raw/fancy-tabs-demo.html

```
var tabs= document.querySelector('fancy-tabs').shadowRoot
tabs.querySelector('#tabs').style.display = none
```

Comment: You need to use querySelectorAll then.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a nodelist. you need to iterate it.

Comment: No problem.   :-)

Comment: Works like a boss - thanks, karthick. **For future googlers:** for Twitter, it was necessary to also add a separate forEach loop to also capture `root.querySelector('article').style.display = 'none';`